# Testing external functions in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix, unittesting, remix-tests

I am writing unit tests on *Remix* (using *Solidity Unit Testing*) for my contract. However, I am having trouble testing `external` functions when `msg.sender` is involved.

The contract:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.14;

contract MyContract {
    address owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier ownerOnly() {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Owner only");
        _; // continue
    }

    function myPublicFunction() public view ownerOnly returns(bool) {
        // DO SOMETHING
        return true;
    }

    function myExternalFunction() external view ownerOnly returns(bool) {
        // DO SOMETHING
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the contract for testing purposes:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

// This import is automatically injected by Remix
import "remix_tests.sol"; 

// This import is required to use custom transaction context
// Although it may fail compilation in 'Solidity Compiler' plugin
// But it will work fine in 'Solidity Unit Testing' plugin
import "remix_accounts.sol";
import "../contracts/MyContract.sol";

contract MyContractTest is MyContract {
    address acc0;

    function beforeAll() public {
        // account at zero index (account-0) is default account (owner)
        acc0 = TestsAccounts.getAccount(0); 
    }

    /// WORKS
    /// #sender: account-0
    function testMyPublicFunction() public {
        Assert.ok(MyPublicFunction(), "Should be true");
    }

    /// DOES NOT WORK
    /// #sender: account-0
    function testMyExternalFunction() {
        Assert.ok(this.MyExternalFunction(), "Should be true");
    }
}
```

In the second test case I get the revert error message from the modifier I have defined. I tried looking at examples on [Remix testing documentation](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unittesting_examples.html), but there isn't one with external functions.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Also, is there a way to get the modifier custom message when a test fails? At the moment the information being displayed is just this:

```
Error Message:
"Transaction has been reverted by the EVM: { 
    "transactionHash": "0xbda418a08e12947ff789335ab92aac44fbce5ac801ad645e17511f1b094cf33c", "transactionIndex": 0, 
    "blockHash": "0x9722db12cccad3bf991bdeeda0117cb8882ce4dd3312356dd7accacdf500b07d", "blockNumber": 55, 
    "gasUsed": 24201, 
    "cumulativeGasUsed": 24201, 
    "status": false, 
    "to": "0x1d142a62E2e98474093545D4A3A0f7DB9503B8BD", 
    "events": {} 
}"
```

Comment: Try the same test, but remove "only Owner" modifier from the function declaration. That was you will be able to pinpoint if that is an issue.

Comment: The modifier is the issue for sure, if I remove it the transaction isn't reverted. I don't understand why `/// #sender: account-0` doesn't work like in the public function test case.

Answer (score 0):

External function has to be called from outside. (And in your case it also has modifier `onlyOwner` ), meaning both cases have to be satisfied.

However, you are calling it from `this`, meaning it will fail if `this` isn't an owner too.

NOTE: `this` is a Solidity keyword that refers to current contract's address.

Comment: That's why I added `/// #sender: account-0`. As far as I know it should set `msg.sender` of that specific call and `account-0` is the owner of the contract. However, it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Because is second test case the sender isn't account-0  but rather MyContrractTest. (Contract has its own address from which it can call other functions)

Comment: Oh, I understand. So how can I make it so that also in the second test case I have account-0 as sender? If I remove .this the compiler can't find the function since it's external and not public.